# Change icon color in Lubuntu 16.10

Tags: lubuntu, icons, themes, preferences

I clicked to accept installation of updates, and when I rebooted my computer the colors of the icons changed to a shade between pink and yellow. I have installed different color themes and control themes but the icons continue to the same as shown in the image.

[image: desktop screenshot]

[image: application bar]

How can you reverse the changes in the colors of the icons?
apologies for my english